# How to set different text to bookmarks in HorizontalCoordinatorNtbActivity

Tags: android

i would like to use HorizontalCoordinatorNtbActivity from this link  https://github.com/Devlight/NavigationTabBar

I have there five of bookmarks (ic_first, ic_second..). On each bookmark are items. Text on items is same for each bookmark..

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.txt.setText(String.format("Navigation Item #%d", position));}
```

How can I have different text in idividual bookmarks? All code is here

```
package devlight.io.sample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import devlight.io.library.ntb.NavigationTabBar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Created by GIGAMOLE on 28.03.
 16.
 */
public class HorizontalCoordinatorNtbActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_horizontal_coordinator_ntb);
        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {
        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vp_horizontal_ntb);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 5;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(final View view, final Object object) {
                return view.equals(object);
            }

            @Override
            public void destroyItem(final View container, final int position, final Object object) {
                ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
            }

            @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position) {
                final View view = LayoutInflater.from(
                        getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_vp_list, null, false);

                final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv);
                recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(
                                getBaseContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false
                        )
                );
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecycleAdapter());

                container.addView(view);
                return view;
            }
        });

        final String[] colors = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.default_preview);

        final NavigationTabBar navigationTabBar = (NavigationTabBar) findViewById(R.id.ntb_horizontal);
        final ArrayList<NavigationTabBar.Model> models = new ArrayList<>();
        models.add(
                new NavigationTabBar.Model.Builder(
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_first),
                        Color.parseColor(colors[0]))
                        .title("Heart")
                        .build()
        );
        models.add(
                new NavigationTabBar.Model.Builder(
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_second),
                        Color.parseColor(colors[1]))
                        .title("Cup")
                        .build()
        );
        models.add(
                new NavigationTabBar.Model.Builder(
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_third),
                        Color.parseColor(colors[2]))
                        .title("Diploma")
                        .build()
        );
        models.add(
                new NavigationTabBar.Model.Builder(
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_fourth),
                        Color.parseColor(colors[3]))
                        .title("Flag")
                        .build()
        );
        models.add(
                new NavigationTabBar.Model.Builder(
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_fifth),
                        Color.parseColor(colors[4]))
                        .title("Medal")
                        .build()
        );

        navigationTabBar.setModels(models);
        navigationTabBar.setViewPager(viewPager, 2);

        //IMPORTANT: ENABLE SCROLL BEHAVIOUR IN COORDINATOR LAYOUT
        navigationTabBar.setBehaviorEnabled(true);

        navigationTabBar.setOnTabBarSelectedIndexListener(new NavigationTabBar.OnTabBarSelectedIndexListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStartTabSelected(final NavigationTabBar.Model model, final int index) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onEndTabSelected(final NavigationTabBar.Model model, final int index) {
                model.hideBadge();
            }
        });
        navigationTabBar.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(final int position, final float positionOffset, final int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(final int position) {



            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(final int state) {

            }
        });

        final CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);
        findViewById(R.id.fab).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                for (int i = 0; i < navigationTabBar.getModels().size(); i++) {
                    final NavigationTabBar.Model model = navigationTabBar.getModels().get(i);
                    navigationTabBar.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            final String title = String.valueOf(new Random().nextInt(15));
                            if (!model.isBadgeShowed()) {
                                model.setBadgeTitle(title);
                                model.showBadge();
                            } else model.updateBadgeTitle(title);
                        }
                    }, i * 100);
                }

                coordinatorLayout.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(navigationTabBar, "Coordinator NTB", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        snackbar.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#9b92b3"));
                        ((TextView) snackbar.getView().findViewById(R.id.snackbar_text))
                                .setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#423752"));
                        snackbar.show();
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
        });

        final CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout =
                (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleColor(Color.parseColor("#009F90AF"));
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setCollapsedTitleTextColor(Color.parseColor("#9f90af"));
    }

    public class RecycleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
            final View view = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.txt.setText(String.format("Navigation Item #%d", position));

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return 20;
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            public TextView txt;

            public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                txt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_vp_item_list);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does it look like currently?

Comment: On the bookmark ic_first is:  Navigation Item #1, Navigation Item #2... and the same on other bookmarks. A would like to have different text (for example bookmark ic_first: Navigation Item #1a, Navigation Item #2a... bookmark ic_second: Navigation Item #1b, Navigation Item #2b...)

Comment: @Marek update it with Question.